# memsql-deploy leaf node consistently failed

Tags: singlestore

On the same host as master to `memsql-deploy` leaf node always failed with same error. Switching the operation to new machines has the same failure.

Here is the steps to deploy master role:

```
# memsql-ops memsql-deploy -a Af53bfb  -r master -P 3306 --community-edition
2017-03-24 16:15:54: Je5725b [INFO] Deploying MemSQL to 172.17.0.3:3306
2017-03-24 16:15:59: Je5725b [INFO] Installing MemSQL
2017-03-24 16:16:02: Je5725b [INFO] Finishing MemSQL Install
Waiting for MemSQL to start...
MemSQL successfully started
```

Here is the immediate steps to add leaf node after deploying master:

```
# memsql-ops memsql-deploy -a Af53bfb  -r leaf -P 3308       
2017-03-24 16:16:43: J32c71f [INFO] Deploying MemSQL to 172.17.0.3:3308
2017-03-24 16:16:43: J32c71f [INFO] Installing MemSQL
2017-03-24 16:16:46: J32c71f [INFO] Finishing MemSQL Install
Waiting for MemSQL to start...
MemSQL failed to start: Failed to start MemSQL:

        set_mempolicy: Operation not permitted
setting membind: Operation not permitted
```

What can be the possible reasons behind the error messages and what way that I can follow to find out the root cause or fix?

Comment: Further dig in to `job-logs` and find a related error message happened during the start of leaf node:  `J2f44c7 [WARNING] Could not read tracelog for MemSQL node 636F0213D6DA91A67D67DD3F4554E20B5CC3FAF1 because it doesn't exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one day search on Google, I believe I finally locate the root cause of this error. I feel strange why no one asked before because it should be happened more often than just me.

The real cause for this issue is I installed `numactl` package per MemSQL's best practice suggestion on a non-NUMA machine. This would effectively  let the memsql node other than the first one try to run `numactl` sub-command `set_mempolicy` to ***bind individual MemSQL nodes to CPUs*** but this command would eventually fails. And the start of the node by sub-commands `memsql-start` or `memsql-deploy` from `memsql-ops` will all fail.

The workaround to this is very simple, just **remove** the package `numactl`. Then everything will be fine. This workaround particularly applies to some virtualization based memsql deployments like **Docker**.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try on the master:

```
memsql-ops start
memsql-ops memsql-deploy --role master -P 3306 --community-edition
```

On the agent:

```
memsql-ops start
memsql-ops follow -h <host of primary agent> -P <port of primary agent if configured to use one>
memsql-ops memsql-deploy --role leaf -P 3308 --community-edition
```

Comment: Both `master` and `leaf` are on the same host. Do I still need to run `follow` prior `memsql-deploy` ?

Comment: @robert I believe so

Comment: though I doubted but I did give it a try. Turned out agent can not follow itself when I do this on `primary` agent box which is also the `master` of memsql. I believe we can only have one memsql agent per host, but we may have one or more nodes per memsql host. There should be other causes to my problem. Thanks.